# Merging Team Project Collections

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have Team Foundation Server 2010 and 3 Team Project Collections on it. I would like to merge them into a single Team Project Collection without losing file version history. Is it possible to move a Team Project from one Team Project Collection to another? I don't have SharePoint or Lab Management.

Answer (score 1):

I have already found the solution - [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/). This product is developed by Team Foundation Server product group and is internally used in Microsoft.